# Action Language for Foundational UML (ALF)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, mda

Is there any Eclipse implementation of the OMG Action Language for Foundational UML (ALF)?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best answer is "it is coming". Papyrus is working on it: http://www.omg.org/news/meetings/tc/agendas/va/xUML_pdf/Cucurru.pdf

there are already some components available on the SVN but I´m not sure how far they are in the process